# Redirect 301 doesn't function properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm quite lost and didn't understand quite well when I'm self researched.

I did a redirect like this

> Redirect 301 /aaa/aaa /bbb/bbb

but when I goes to **aaa/aaa**, it was redirected to **/bbb/aaa**

I understand (assumed) that it was because I already have a this line

> Redirect 301 /aaa /bbb

There were about 60 redirection line implemented at the same time, but only some of 'em got this issue. I'm not very familiar with the coding field, so I'm open for any advices.

Thank you

Comment: You mean to say that with both redirect config in place, one some of 60 requests moved to /bbb/aaa and some went otherwise? And input for all 60 was same?

Comment: Keep `Redirect 301 /aaa/aaa /bbb/bbb` above other rule and clear browser cache.

Comment: Hi NitinSingh, I meant that there are both redirect config in place. The input for all 60 are the same in terms of formula (Redirect 301 /xxx /yyy). Only some of the 60 requested are moved to bbb/aaa but the rest of them moved correctly as intended.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thank you for your suggestion, I tried move the troubled line to the top above all the other rules and gave it a couple hours + clearing cache to check but it still doesn't works though.